# ¿Cual es la equivalencia de $_REQUEST en Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentado hacer algo así como una "tienda" y el sistema de pagos lo elegí porque ofrece un modo para desarrollador y te puedes inventar cualquier cosa con eso. Siguiendo el tema, yo puedo hacer POST al sistema para generar una dirección de pago sin problemas, algo así:

```php
$receiverId = IDDEMICUENTADEV;
$secretKey = 'abecedario1234aaaaabbbbccccdeee';

$configuration = new Khipu\Configuration();
$configuration->setReceiverId($receiverId);
$configuration->setSecret($secretKey);

$client = new Khipu\ApiClient($configuration);
$payments = new Khipu\Client\PaymentsApi($client);

try {
    $opts = array(
        "transaction_id" => "MTI-100",
        "return_url" => "http://mi-ecomerce.com/backend/return",
        "cancel_url" => "http://mi-ecomerce.com/backend/cancel",
        "picture_url" => "http://mi-ecomerce.com/pictures/foto-producto.jpg",
        "notify_url" => "http://mi-ecomerce.com/backend/notify",
        "notify_api_version" => "1.3"
    );
    $response = $payments->paymentsPost(
        "Compra de prueba de la API", //Motivo de la compra
        "CLP", //Moneda
        100.0, //Monto
        $opts //campos opcionales
);

    print_r($response);// ESTO me devuelve un json con la url para pagar
} catch (\Khipu\ApiException $e) {
    echo print_r($e->getResponseBody(), TRUE);
}
```

Usando por supuesto la librería que ofrecen(está por aquí) https://khipu.com/developers

En el campo "notify_url" del array se establece la dirección en donde el procesador hace la notificación desde una API a través del método POST el cual trae dos parámetos(los cuales no puedo capturar).

Creé una función en el controlador asociado a la ruta de pago, algo así:

```js
public function getNotify(Request $request){

$receiver_id = MIIDDECUENTA;
$secret = 'abecedario123aaaaabbbbbccccdddeeee';

$request->api_version = $api_version;

$request->notification_token = $notification_token;

try {
    if ($api_version == '1.3') {
        $configuration = new Khipu\Configuration();
        $configuration->setSecret($secret);
        $configuration->setReceiverId($receiver_id);
        // $configuration->setDebug(true);

        $client = new Khipu\ApiClient($configuration);
        $payments = new Khipu\Client\PaymentsApi($client);

        $response = $payments->paymentsGet($notification_token);
        if ($response->getReceiverId() == $receiver_id) {
            if ($response->getStatus() == 'done' && $response->getAmount() == $amount) {
                // marcar el pago como completo y entregar el bien o servicio
            }
        } else {
            // receiver_id no coincide
        }
    } else {
        // Usar versión anterior de la API de notificación
    }
} catch (\Khipu\ApiException $exception) {
    print_r($exception->getResponseObject());
}
}
```

Originalmente el script lee el Api_version y el notification_token con $_REQUEST.

Al intentar hacer post al URL la aplicación me manda a hacer login. No sé por qué suceda

Liberé de el csrf la ruta pues en la documentación de laravel leí que a veces da problemas, la añadí a la excepción del middleware y aun así no puedo capturar los datos, estos los necesito para validar el "pago" y entregar el producto.

Comment: Esta ruta "http://mi-ecomerce.com/backend/notify" ya está enlazada a la función getNotify de tu controlador en el archivo routes verdad?... si escribes esta linea al principio de tu función que resultados te da?: dd($request->all());

Comment: @Bryan Retamal Si, la ruta "notify" está enlazada a la función del controlador, estoy probando lo de dump & die como lo has dicho. Actualizo en un momento

Comment: @Bryan Retamal Acabo de recrear todo de nuevo, puesto que andaba buscado otras soluciones. Como es un lugar que recibe la notificación tuve que retornar un view al final de la función payNotify() que estuviese en blanco para visualizar lo que pasa, aun así, el dd($request->all()) no me muestra nada. Quizá algún error mío, seguiré intentando.

Comment: Si intento hacer POST a la ruta con Postman esta me manda a iniciar sesión.

Comment: Muéstrame por favor tu archivo de rutas